# C# Generic Class, how can I use public properties of derived class of type parameter?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, generics, constraints

I have two classes in C#:

```
public abstract class BaseAccount
{
    public void MyMethod1()
    {
        //Code
    }
}

public class DerivedAccount : BaseAccount
{
    public  void MyMethod2()
    {
        //code
    }
}

public class AccountBL<T> where T : BaseAccount, new()
{
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        T obj1 = new T();
        obj1.MyMethod1();
        obj1.MyMethod2(); //Wrong!!! Can I use a method in derived class without changing constaint??
    }       
}
```

How can I use **public properties** of a derived class in the generic class?

I don't want implement several generic class for each of my Derived Class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `DerivedAccount.Method2()`, this wish already *is* a constraint. You obviously need `T` to be DerivedAccount.

You *could* do something like that:

```
 (obj1 as DerivedAccount)?.MyMethod2();
```

but I personally don't like to mix type casts and generics. If your method is generic, it means you don't care about the specific runtime type (except it should be `BaseAccount`). Then adding type checks seems a little odd.

Answer (score 3):

Define an interface that includes the members you want to access, and then restrict the type parameter to types that implement that interface.

```
public IMyInterface {
  void MyMethod2();
}

public class AccountBL<T> where T : BaseAccounbt, new(), IMyInterface {
  // Members can access T.MyMethod2()
}
```

Unlike other some languages, C# only allows reference to members on type parameters that fit the requirements imposed on the type parameters.

Comment: it can be good, but is a little hard to understand.
and i am not sure, can be large scale or not?
need more think...
thanks

Comment: @nimakhankhanizadeh What do you mean by "large scale"?

Answer (score 2):

It is because your Structure. With `where T : BaseAccount, new()` your're saying that T has to inherit from `BaseAccount` so you can use the methods from `BaseAccount`. If you want to use the Methods from `DerivedAccount` you have to check this first:

```
if (obj1 is DerivedAccount ) {}
```

And than cast it as `DerivedAccount`. so you get the following:

```
public class AccountBL<T> where T : BaseAccount, new()
{
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        T obj1 = new T();
        obj1.MyMethod1();

        if (obj1 is DerivedAccount )
        {
             (obj1 as DerivedAccount).MyMethod2();
        }
    }       
}
```

Here you have an executable example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NwxPRt

Answer (score 0):

It is because your Structure. With where `T : BaseAccount, new()` your're saying that T has to inherit from `BaseAccount` so you can use the methods from `BaseAccount`. If you want to use the Methods from `DerivedAccount` you have to check this first.